# There is a border-radius around a Slider Revolution slide, but I can't find the CSS

Tags: css

On [this page](http://staging.venusanddiamonds.com/), there is a Slider Revolution slider with one slide (at the moment).

The slide contains 4 rounded corners, revealing a white background underneath, but I cannot see what CSS is producing these rounded corners.

[image]

I have right-clicked on that white background, selected Inspect Element, and gone through each element, up the chain, and can see no instance of border-radius in the CSS.

Can you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check .tp-bgimg.defaultimg in style.css, line 4279

It affects this element:

```
<div class="tp-bgimg defaultimg" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;opacity: 1;visibility: inherit;z-index: 20;/* background-image: url(&quot;http://staging.venusanddiamonds.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/slide0.jpg&quot;); */background-color: rgba(255, 0, 1,1);background-size: cover;background-position: 50% 50%;background-repeat: no-repeat;" src="http://staging.venusanddiamonds.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/slide0.jpg"></div>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Well spotted TheFonet!

Answer (score 3):

It's `.tp-bgimg.defaultimg` element - [screenshot](http://c2n.me/3yplQpU)

Answer (score 1):

Remove this from  Style.css

```
  .tp-bgimg.defaultimg {
  border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-o-border-radius: 5px;
 }
```